# Retornar o nome no lugar do ID em um relacionamento em Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-record

Tenho duas tabelas relacionadas no Rails, `pessoa` e `cidade`.

Na tabela `pessoa` tenho o campo `cidade_id`.

Como fazer, por exemplo, `p = Pessoa.find(1)` e no lugar de `p.cidade_id` já retornar o nome da cidade sem eu precisar fazer `p.cidade.nome`?

Answer (score 3):

Você pode fazer a busca pelo nome da cidade na mesma busca para encontrar a pessoa, usando o `includes` que não fará query adicional. Seria algo como:

```
Person.includes(:city).where(id: 1).pluck(:name, 'cities.name')
```

contanto que exista no seu código essa associação mapeada no model.

Usando o `includes`, mesmo se no seu loop você precisar chamar `p.cidade.nome`, não serão feitas queries adicionais.

**DICA**: Vale dar uma pesquisada em `preload x includes x joins` para que você sempre possa escolher qual método aplicar.

Comment: muito obrigado deu certo, estou usando como api então é so usar  render :json => @people.to_json(:include => :city) no controlador que retorna 1 json {people: {id: 1, name: "teste"...} city:{id:1 name: ...} }